# Justifying an inequality

Tags: measure-theory, inequality, solution-verification, proof-writing

I am reading Banach Spaces of Analytic Functions by Hoffman. In Page 52, the authors claim this inequality as passing remark:

> Let $f \in L^1 (\mathbb T)$ and $f(e^{i0})\ne 0$ and suppose that $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int \log (|f| +\varepsilon) d\theta \ge \log |f(e^{i0})| \qquad  \forall \varepsilon >0$$ We can then show that:
> $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int \log (|f|) d\theta \ge \log |f(e^{i0})|$$

I initially thought of using [Fatou's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma) to prove this but I do not think that will work here. Is there any other way passing the limit inside the integral here?

---

**EDIT**

I think I have found the proof but I would like some verification.

Note that:

$$1 = \log e \le\log (|f| + e) \le |f| +e$$ Hence, $\log (|f| + e)$ is integrable. We have that $\log(|f| + 1/n) \le \log (|f|+e)$ for every $n \in \mathbb N$ by assumption. Thus, we have that by Dominated Convergence theorem that $$\int \log(|f|) \frac{d\theta}{2\pi}= \lim_{n\to \infty} \int \log(|f| + 1/n) \frac{d\theta}{2\pi}$$

Comment: The question does not make sense since $f(0)$ is not a well defined number.

Comment: @geetha290krm I have made necessary changes

Comment: $L^{1}$ consists of equivalence classes of functions. Do you want to assume continuity of $f$?

Comment: No. I am writing $f\in L^1 = \mathcal {L} ^1$ by abusing the notation as often done in textbooks.

Comment: Hoffman is talking about $f \in H^{1}$, not $L^{1}$.

Comment: @geetha290krm I agree. But I think one does not need $H^1$ to prove that inequality. I made an edit to prove my inequality. Can you take  a look , please?